# Java Runtime exec: permission denied

Tags: java, runtime, ioexception

I am trying to do the following (as a simplistic example):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/Applications/TextEdit.app");
    }
}
```

but an error occurs:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Applications/TextEdit.app": error=13, Permission denied
```

obviously, the actual user executing the jvm has not the rights to execute TextEdit. How can I change that?

...

solved it myself in the comment

Comment: ok I am an idiot, changed the path to the actual executable: `/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit`, now it works

Comment: Well yes ... you can't execute a directory.  If you really want it to be dead, you need to `rmdir` it :-)

Comment: @Eike, you can use the `open` command: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("open -a TextEdit")`;

Comment: @EikeCochu, if you've solved the problem yourself, you can add your own solution as an answer to this question.